# Reverse the order of repeater field in admin area - advanced customfields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Is there a clean way to reverse the order of ACF repeater rows in admin area ?

I know how to reverse the rows on the front-end with a PHP query.

But im looking for a clean way to reverse the order in the admin area.

Is this possible and how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer was quite easy. And it was staring into my face all a long.

Place this in your child-theme functions.php file or your preferred file for controlling this

```
function my_acf_load_value( $value, $post_id, $field ) {

    $order = array();

    if( empty($value) ) {
        return $value;
    }

    // populate order
    // Remember to change the field_5a4d0e70a5d3f to the field that you want to sort by
    foreach( $value as $i => $row ) {
        $order[ $i ] = $row['field_5a4d0e70a5d3f'];
    }

    array_multisort( $order, SORT_DESC, $value );

    return $value;
}
// Remember to change "book_repeater" to your repeater field name
add_filter('acf/load_value/name=book_repeater', 'my_acf_load_value', 10, 3);
```

Now your repeater fields will be sorted by the field_5a4d0e70a5d3f

There are a few options for the sorting direction, these are: SORT_ASC, SORT_DESC, SORT_REGULAR, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_STRING.